# Teamviewer on Raspbian lite

Tags: raspbian, headless

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian lite (without X server). Can I setup and use Teamviewer (or something similar) to access my Raspberry from anywhere using only command line?

The program should work like Teamviewer: no port forwarding, needing to know the IP etc.

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking for a command line solution because your RPi is headless, or because you specifically only want to use the command line? The RPi foundation offers a free VNC service. Although your RPi is headless, it can run as a VNC server. You'd use a GUI VNC viewer to access it however. Is that useful? See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SSH is the default way to interact cli only with a system. In the newest image of raspbian ssh is disabled by default, you can enabled it by creating a file 'ssh' in the boot partition.

To connect to your raspberry pi, get its IP(internal if you are on the same network) and use a ssh client to connect to it.

On windows this will be putty for example.
On all Linux distros you can run ssh from the terminal eq:

```
ssh -l pi 192.168.0.100
```

Here is ssh the command for ssh, -l is for the login name(it is pi here) and 192.168.0.100 is the internal IP for my pi.

Comment: You don't understand the question. Key words are: "from anywhere", i. e. without knowing Pi's IP, setting up port forwarding, etc.

Comment: You never specified no port forwarding. I included "IP(internal if you are on the same network)".

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, you'd need to set up SSH access on the PI.

To avoid the 'needing to know the IP' but, you can use a service such as dyn dns to provide an easily remembered host-name, which automatically keeps track of changes to your external address.

to do this, you will need to configure :-

1. SSH access to the RPi
2. Port Forwarding from your router/internet to your RPi.
3. Dynamic DNS from a provider (dyndns is one of many)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at tmate.

tmate.io

Running tmate will give a ssh address to connect to. Then share the address or use it remotely.